# How do I select sequential numbers for non-unique values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've got a column with non-unique values like so:

```
ID      COL_A
0       A
1       B
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       D
6       D
7       E
```

I would like to select an offset in addition to those two columns which produces the following output:

```
ID      COL_A     OFFSET
0       A         0
1       B         0
2       B         1
3       C         0
4       D         0
5       D         1
6       D         2
7       E         0
```

The offset should be applied so that the value with the lower primary key receives the lower offset.

I could probably come up with a PL/SQL approach to get this, but is this possible in pure SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `row_number()` window function is just what the doctor prescribed:

```
SELECT id, col_a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_a ORDER BY id) - 1 AS offset
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Accepted your answer since you used the appropriate column names. I also added `- 1` to make the offset start at 0, but this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

USE ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2 ORDER BY Col1) Seq
FROM TableNAme
```